# How to get a .bmp Image file pixels value with jython

Tags: python, image, bitmap, jython

i want to get a pixel RGB with jython.
how can i get the pixel value of a .bmp file with a usual module or no module in jython.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look @ [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) google tells me this it should work with jython.